# Icon onPress only working for Android and not iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to make a custom header component with an icon that can either toggle the navigation drawer or navigate the user back (or anywhere), the button is working fine on Android but doesn't seem to register the onPress on iOS.
I tried playing with position absolute and relative but the issue persisted.

```
//Component code
    const HeaderArrow: React.FC<Props> =  (props) =>{
        return(
            <View style={[styles.HeaderContainer, props.HeaderStyle]}>
                <Icon name={props.iconName} size={35} color={props.iconColor} onPress={() => props.navigateMeBack()}/>
                <View style={{position: 'relative', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                <Text style={[styles.TextStyle, props.TextEdited]}>
                    {props.HeaderText}
                </Text>
                </View> 
            </View>
        )
    }
    
    const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
        HeaderContainer:{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            backgroundColor: '#f8f8f8',
            alignItems: 'center',
            width: WIDTH,
            paddingVertical: '5rem',
            marginHorizontal: '5rem',
        },
        TextStyle:{
            fontSize: '18rem',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: Colors.mainHeader,
        }
    })

// Main screen code<HeaderArrow
        HeaderText={'Sign up (1 of 2)'}
        HeaderStyle={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}
        TextEdited={GlobalStyles.headerTextStyle}
        navigateMeBack={() => backToLogin()}
        iconName={'arrow-left'}
        iconColor={Colors.mainForeGround}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.navigateMeBack()} >
  <Icon 
    name={props.iconName} 
    size={35}
    color={props.iconColor}   
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Tried it before i posted the question, doesn't work.

Comment: The button only works when flexDirection: 'row' is removed, still working on a solution.